# How to restrict directory with ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want a process to have `write` access to only one directory. If the process attempts to write to another directory, it should be restricted.

I tried `directory()` method, but this only sets default.

```
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
 File allowedDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/allowedDirectory/"); 

 // setting allowed directory 
 processBuilder.directory(allowedDir); 

 //expect this to fail 
 processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "rmdir /s /q \"C:\\Users\\restrictedDirectory\\restrictedFolder\""); 
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        int errCode = process.waitFor();
```

**However the command that I was expecting to fail, works and removes files in the `restrictedDirectory`. How to restrict `ProcessBuilder` to have `write` access to only a single directory?**

Comment: You cannot restrict access to directories like that. Only OS-level security can do that. This question is off topic, because it is not a programming problem. Ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible - ProcessBuilder simply executes programs on your computer, it doesn't run them in a sandbox.

[`ProcessBuilder#directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) sets the *working directory* for the process.

Comment: thank you . then how to make the command in my question run and fail? what is the standard for this? security manager?

Comment: You can't. SecurityManagers can only control resources in Java. If this is really required, you're better off writing whatever you want to run in Java so a SecurityManager could control it. If you simply want to delete a directory, that's a pretty trivial `Files#delete(Path)`.